# SwiftUI: Gesture doesn't work , it won't move

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an array of `User` and my goal is to build something like Tinder. So user can swipe right or left, but I failed at the Gesture, the card won't event move

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var users: [User] = [
        User(id: "1", imageName: "Card2", position: CGSize.zero),
        User(id: "2", imageName: "Card3", position: CGSize.zero),
        User(id: "3", imageName: "Card4", position: CGSize.zero)
    ]

    var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                ForEach(users, id: \.imageName) { user in
                    CardView(imageName: user.imageName, position: user.position)
                        .offset(x: user.position.width, y: user.position.height)
                        .animation(.spring(response: 0.3, dampingFraction: 0.6, blendDuration: 0))
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture()
                                .onChanged { value in
                                    user.position = value.translation

                                }
                                .onEnded { value in
                                    user.position = .zero
                                }
                    )
                }

            }
    }
}
```

This is the user struct

```
struct User: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var imageName: String
    @State var position: CGSize
}
```

The Card, it doesn't move when I try to move it.

[image]

Comment: Inside for each you work with copy of user that's why nothing changed, start from making model observable and then decompose everything CardView related inside it.

Comment: Mind giving some suggestions? thanks